# how to upload file in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file into server but upload file should be mis place

Here is my code

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$userid=$_REQUEST['UserName'];
$filename=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$filename=str_replace(' ','|',$filename);

//echo $tmppath;

$path = "UserIds/";
$di = $path . $userid;

mkdir($di,0777);

$dir=$di . "/" . date("Y-F-d");

mkdir($dir, 0777, TRUE);
$tmppath=$dir."/".$filename;
// echo $tmppath;

if($filename) {
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$tmppath)) {
    $message=array("message"=>"successfully uploaded","location"=>"http://www.myappdemo.com/appinstaller/$dir/".$filename);
  } else {
    $message=array("message"=>"file uploading failed");
  }
} else {
  $message=array("message"=>"provide values");
}
echo json_encode($message);
?>
```

here create directory is fine but upload file in mis place please guide me

thanks for advance

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but using | in filenames could give problems. on windows for example you cannot use that in filenames. Instead replace it with an underscore:

```
$filename=str_replace(' ','_',$filename);
```